# using psql to export to a csv in python

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2, psql

I have a very simple psql command to export a table to a csv

```
\COPY report TO '\path\reprot.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

how can I run this command in python?

*I have psycopg2 installed

Comment: Use the `copy_expert()` method of a cursor: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert. How exactly depends on what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Since you have `CSV` there, `DELIMITER ','` is unnecessary. COPY defaults to comma, when Comma Separated Values are requested.

Comment: @IljaEverilä so what should the statement be?!

Comment: using the copy expert

Comment: From the linked documentation: "The *sql* statement should be in the form `COPY table TO STDOUT` to export `table` to the file object passed as argument".

Comment: okay that worked but I want to be able to specify a specific path where to store it

Answer (score 0):

you can use python's [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: im aware but I want to know how to do in pysocpg2 or psql within python

Comment: did you find out how?